# Display menu horizontal with vertical drop down?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am trying to build a drop down menu, So far i found a really nice menu but it lists its items horizontal and displays its sub items horizontally as well.

I would like my items to be next to each other and then if it has a sub menu those items drop down.

Here is my Menu:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../Content/Menu.css" />
  <div class="float-right">
    <nav>
      <ul class="menu" style="float: left;">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#" class="">Home</a>
          <ul style="display: block; ">
            <li class="subitem1" >@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new { @class = "active" })</li>
            <li class="subitem2">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
            <li class="subitem3">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item2">@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home")</li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
```

---

Style Sheet

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    background:#32373d;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul, ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#wrapper {  
    width: 220px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-size: 0.8125em;
}
.menu {
    width: 225px;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.73), 0px 0px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.13);
}
.menu > li > a {
    background-color: #616975;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(114, 122, 134)),to(rgb(80, 88, 100)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134), rgb(80, 88, 100));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#727a86', EndColorStr='#505864');
    border-bottom: 1px solid #33373d;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #878e98;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
.menu ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efeff0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.923em;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #878d95;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #33373d;
}
.menu > li > a:hover, .menu > li > a.active {
    background-color: #35afe3;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgb(69, 199, 235)),to(rgb(38, 152, 219)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgb(69, 199, 235), rgb(38, 152, 219));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,StartColorStr='#45c7eb', EndColorStr='#2698db');
    border-bottom: 1px solid #103c56;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #6ad2ef;
}
.menu > li > a.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1a638f;
}
.menu > li > a:before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url(../images/sprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -.5em 0 0 0;
}
.item1 > a:before {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.item2 > a:before {
    background-position: -38px 0;
}
.item3 > a:before {
    background-position: 0 -38px;
}
.item4 > a:before {
    background-position: -38px -38px;
}
.item5 > a:before {
    background-position: -76px 0;
}
.menu > li > a span {
    font-size: 0.857em; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 50%; 
    background: #48515c;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    padding: .4em .6em;
    margin: -.8em 0 0 0; 
    color: #fff;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: .769em;
    -moz-border-radius: .769em;
    border-radius: .769em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .26), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    font-weight: 500;
}
.menu > li > a:hover span, .menu > li a.active span {
    background: #2173a1;
}
.menu > li > ul li a:before{
    content: '▶';
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #bcbcbf;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    top: 0;
    left: -2.7em;
}

.menu > li > ul li:hover a,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a span,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a:before {
    color: #32373D;
}


.menu ul > li > a span {
    font-size: 0.857em; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 1em;
    top: 50%; /
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d3;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    padding: .4em .7em;
    margin: -.9em 0 0 0; 
    color: #878d95;
    text-indent: 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: .769em;
    -moz-border-radius: 769em;
    border-radius: 769em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.01));
}
```

What property in my style sheet is causing my Menu to list like this?

Is there a way to override what every is causing the menu you to do this?

---

Edit

Html list:

```
<div class="float-right">
  <nav>
    <ul class="menu" style="float: left;">
      <li class="item1"><a href="#" class="">Home</a>
        <ul style="display: block; ">
          <li class="subitem1" ><a class="active" href="/?Length=4">Home</a></li>
          <li class="subitem2"><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="subitem3"><a href="/Home/About">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item2"><a href="/Home/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your RENDERED html code, not your freemarker template (or whatever it is that thing starting with '@')

Comment: That's how you create a link in MVC

Comment: Ok, but JSFiddle does not decode Spring MVC code. Open your page, click View Source and post that please ;)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Ok i have posted the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.menu {
  width: 225px;
}
```

the *width:225px* prevents the menu from displaying correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/wFyMs/2/

Comment: I removed that width and it had no affect?

Comment: then see the link i posted, i added a few new lines at the bottom of the css. accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I added those extra lines and its working, the sub menu's are a bit to long but it is behaving like i wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Why can you make it simplier?

Try rewrite it by this pattern:

**CSS**

```
li { float: left; }
li ul li { clear: both; }
```

Comment: This menu was used some where else in my website and now i would like to use it again but horizontal, i would like to have them work that same. So i cant make it to simple as this is how the client wants it. But that's for a push in the right direction, those two style codes does list the menu horizontal, it just messed up some other styling.

Comment: So give specific `id` for first `ul` and style it by it.